# IE not applying CSS to JS, works in Chrome/FF

Tags: javascript, css, internet-explorer, blogger

For [my site](http://blog.onlinewagerreview.com/), which is based on Blogger, I use a widget called "recent articles". The styles apply in both Firefox and Chrome, but not in IE.

I am new to web development and do not know JS.

### Specific CSS not being applied (title of articles):

```
.bp_item_title {
    margin: 10px 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-family: Tahoma,Geneva,sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
}
```

I tested this in firebug on IE and it looks like the CSS style are not being attached to the elements. Why would IE not pass along these CSS styles to the elements/widget?

### HTML Snippet

```
<!-- ... -->
<div class="widget-content">
<div id="bp_recent"><div class="bp_item_title"><a href="http://blog.onlinewagerreview.com/2012/05/miami-heat-vs-boston-celtics-game-2.html?utm_source=BP_recent&amp;utm-medium=gadget&amp;utm_campaign=bp_recent" target="_top" title="Miami Heat vs Boston Celtics, Game 2 Free Pick, Prediction">Miami Heat vs Boston Celtics, Game 2 Free Pick, Prediction</a></div>
```

```javascript
    if (showThumbs == true && thumbUrl != "") {
        myImage = document.createElement('img');
        myImage.setAttribute("src", thumbUrl);
        if(imgFloat!="none")
        {
        float_clear=true;
        myImage.style.cssFloat=imgFloat;
        myImage.style.styleFloat=imgFloat;
        }
      try{if(myMargin!=0)myImage.style.margin = myMargin+"px";} catch(error){}
        myImage.setAttribute("alt", postTitleOriginal);
        myImage.setAttribute("width", imgDim);
        myImage.setAttribute("height", imgDim);
        myLink = document.createElement('a');
        myLink.setAttribute("href", postUrl+"?utm_source=bp_recent&utm-medium=gadget&utm_campaign=bp_recent");
        myLink.setAttribute("target", "_top");
        myLink.setAttribute("title", postTitleOriginal);
        myLink.appendChild(myImage);

        myDiv = document.createElement('div');
        myDiv.setAttribute("class", "bp_item_thumb");
        myDiv.appendChild(myLink);
        main.appendChild(myDiv);
    }
```

[Source](http://onlinewagerreview.com/js/recentposts.js)

Comment: where in the HTML is `.bp_item_title`?

Comment: <div class="widget-content">
<div id="bp_recent"><div class="bp_item_title">

Comment: It's way too much code for me to read and help.. sorry. From the lack of answers, I would think others agree. Coming up with a reduction of the problem is the best way for SO users to be able to help without dedicating a lot of time

Comment: Yes, I agree.  I am sorry the question displayed this way.  I will try to edit or repost it correctly.

Comment: I have reduced the code, so it is easier to read.

Answer (score 1):

`setAttribute()` does not work in IE for the `style` attribute. To support IE, use `element.className = 'newClass';`. It would also be a good idea to use a function that checks if the `class` attribute is already set to a non-blank value and include those values when setting it. For example:

```javascript
// $el is the element to add $class to
// $class is the string value to append to `class` attribute
function addClass($el, $class) {
 if(!$el){
  return false;
 }
    $c = $el.className;
    if (($c === null) || ($c === '')) {
        $el.className = $class;
    } else if ($c.indexOf($class) === -1) {
        $el.className = $c + ' ' + $class;
    }
}

// $el is the element to remove $class from
// $class is the string value to remove from `class` attribute
function removeClass($el, $class) {
 if(!$el){
  return false;
 }
    $c = $el.className;
    if (($c !== null) && ($c !== '') && ($c.indexOf($class) !== -1)) {
        if ($c.indexOf($class) === 0) $el.className = $c.replace($class, '');
                else $el.className = $c.replace(' ' + $class, ''); 
    }
}
```

Or simply set the `class` attribute to a new value (instead of appending a new class or removing an individual class):

```
myDiv.className = "bp_item_thumb";
```

...instead of...

```
myDiv.setAttribute("class", "bp_item_thumb");
```

Comment: Thanks bfrohs for the answer!  But I should add...I did not write this js script.  Is there a straight forward way (code I could add) to have IE recognize my css styles on this script?

Comment: @GregC., see the updated answer. Basically, just replace `.setAttribute("class", ...);` with `.className = ...;`.

Comment: It worked!!  Thank you so much...I have been struggling with this all day.  I cant thank you enough for your help!

Comment: @GregC. Glad to hear it :) Be sure to accept this answer when you get a chance (see [How do I ask questions here?](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask) in the FAQ).